# Whats wrong with my PHP/SQL Query (won't read from SQL)(login system)

Tags: php, html, mysql, authentication, windows-2000

I am coding a login system and the php code I'm writing has no error messages and when I use a wrong password there are still no errors or success messages. I have a feeling that the PHP is not reading the SQL but can one of you point this out and tell me how to fix it?

```
<?php
    $accounts = mysql_connect("localhost" , "root" , "placeholder") or die (mysql_error());
    $loginname = $_POST['loginname'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    $needle = '@';
    $search = strpos($loginname, $needle);

    if ( isset($loginname) )
    {
        mysql_select_db("nematznetwork", $accounts);
        //$username = "test <br>";
        //$password = 'pass';
        //$accounts;
        //echo $loginname . "<br>";
        //echo $password;


        if($search === FALSE)
        {
            //USERNAME
            $username = $loginname;
            $usernamesql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='" . $username . "'";
            $usernameresults = mysql_query($usernamesql, $accounts);
            while($usernamerow = mysql_fetch_array($usernameresults))
            {
                $usernamecorrect = 'yes';
                $dbpassword = $usernamerow['password'];
            }
        }
        else
        {
            //EMAIL
            $email = $loginname
            $emailsql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email='" . $email . "'";
            $emailresults = mysql_query($emailsql, $accounts);
            while($emailrow = mysql_fetch_array($emailresults))
            {
                $usernamecorrect = 'yes';
                $dbpassword = $emailrow['password'];
            }
        }

        if($dbpassword == $password)
        {
            //COOKIE GOES HERE
            //NO COOKIE YET
        }
        else
        {
            //PASSWORD ERROR GOES HERE
            $error = 'true';
        }
    }
    else
    {
        //NO USER NAME VARIABLE GOES HERE
        $error = 'true';
    }

    if ( isset($usernamecorrect) )
    {
    }
    else
    {
        //WRONG USER NAME VARIABLE GOES HERE
        $error = 'true';
    }

    if ( isset($error) )
    {
        //ERROR MESSAGE FOR INCORRECT USERNAME/EMAIL/PASSWORD
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>\n";
        echo "alert('The Username/Email or Password you entered was incorrect.');\n";
        echo "window.location = “http://www.google.com;\n";
        echo "</script>";
    }
    else
    {

    }

?>
```

Comment: Have u run the script(webpage) in localhost...

Comment: Your major problem is having gaping wide-open [SQL injection attack](http://bobby-tables.com) holes, leaving you utterly BEGGING to get your server destroyed.

Comment: Aminul-Yes, Marc B-What do you mean, Im just beginning

Comment: A few things here - your `isset($loginname)` will always return true, since you have defined it elsewhere. I think you meant `isset($_POST['loginname'])`. Also, `$username` comes from tainted user input, and so creates a SQL injection problem in your query. Your next step is to add `echo` and `exit` statements to trace where your program execution is going. Finally, do use indentation - it makes things easier for you, and for readers here.

Comment: Marc's link isn't that great, imo, in explaining what "SQL injection" is. Essentially it's permitting your user to run their own SQL statements on your database server in a manner that you did not intend, arising from a failure to validate input. Search for it on this website - there are loads of resources for it.

Comment: I use NP++ so it is easier for me to read, sorry that it is not this way here. How is $username tainted

Comment: "tainted" means that the user can put SQL code in there and it will be run by your database.

Comment: after fetching the username from user, just echo the password in while loop....
if it successful then you have no problem with mysql connection.

Answer (score 0):

It is very hard to give you a clear answer as there are a number of reasons why you may not be getting either an answer or errors.

The trouble with computers is they do what you tell them.

Firstly, it is vitally important that you do not send unescaped user input to your server, especially like this. There are 'universal passwords' that will easily unlock this system.
Ensure you use mysqli_real_escape_string or prepared statements.

Secondly, please start off the right way, using mysqli_* or PDO rather than mysql_* which will be removed soon.

Thirdly, consider storing passwords as a hash.

To debug this, you need to test each level.  Echo your SQL and echo the result of the query.  It will soon become obvious where the data you receive from your DB is not matching the data you expect.

Overall, I'd probably call ths code a deader and start again.  Safer and more worth your time.

Comment: is the syntax of mysqli_* the same as mysql_*?

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using a function for checking login, that way you can use "return FALSE;" everywhere something went wrong.

Here is an example, also added a DEBUG constant, that can be TRUE or FALSE depending on whether you want debug output or just use the function.

```
<?php

    define('DEBUG', TRUE);

    if(login($_POST['loginname'], $_POST['password']))
    {
        // cookies and stuff
    }
    else
    {
        // error message and stuff
    }

    function login($username, $password)
    {
        $database_link = mysql_connect("localhost" , "root" , "placeholder");

        if(!$database_link)
        {
            if(DEBUG)
            {
                die("Failed to connect to database: " . mysql_error());
            }
            return FALASE;
        }

        mysql_select_db("nematznetwork", $database_link);

        if(strpos($username, '@'))
        {
            $search_field = 'email';
        }
        else
        {
            $search_field = 'username';
        }

        $query = "SELECT * FROM useres WHERE {$search_field} = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['loginname']) ."'";
        $resource = mysql_query($query, $database_link);

        if(!$resource)
        {
            if(DEBUG)
            {
                die("Failed to query database: " . mysql_error());
            }
            return FALASE;
        }

        $result = mysql_fetch_assoc($resource);

        if(!$result)
        {
            if(DEBUG)
            {
                die("Username not found");
            }
            return FALSE;
        }

        if(!$result['password'])
        {
            if(DEBUG)
            {
                die("User have no password");
            }
            return FALSE;
        }

        if($result['password'] == $password)
        {
            return TRUE;
        }
        else
        {
            if(DEBUG)
            {
                die("Wrong password");
            }
            return FALSE;
        }
    }

?>
```

And as Roberts says, mysql_ functions are deprecated in PHP 5.5

Comment: Will this work with my current setup? What mods do I have to make to test it?

Comment: yes, just add somthing at the comments at the top, most of the code is rearanged rows from your oringinal, renamed the varas handling the database to describe waht it contains: datbase_link, query, resource, result, and added some debugoutput.